# Creation of bug specification

Tags: documentation

I am currently testing a piece of vehicle management software. To kill two birds with one stone I am also going to create a user guide, alongside a similar document to point out and describe bugs.

The document would need to be in a PDF format and would be screenshot heavy.

If anybody has done anything similar could you advise a piece of software fit for this job? I.E PDF creation, snipping tool?

I am trying to avoid word at all costs.

Comment: What kind of document is it, where you're pointing out and describing bugs? Is this document for internal use, or for customers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you mentioned Word, I assume the tool (and the user interface for the software under test) run on Windows.  There are a lot of free or inexpensive screen capture utilities for Windows.  [This article](http://lifehacker.com/5880928/the-best-screen-capture-tool-for-windows) recommends [PicPick](http://www.picpick.org/) but also mentions several others.

Regarding document editing tools that can produce a PDF, I recommend using Google Drive.

Of course this does not constitute a bug tracking system, but you did not ask for one.

Comment: No I am not currently looking for a bug tracking solution at the moment. I will have a look at that article now. And yes sorry I forgot to stipulate I was using windows, many thanks for your answer.